# Image in button CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button below and I am trying to add an image to the left of the text. Is there anyway to do this with this image: http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1498058230/HR-Connect-Logo_hjbrmn.png without changing the height of the button? I am able to put the image in the button but it keeps messing with the height. Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.button_slide {
  color: #156466;
  border: 1px solid rgba(21,100,102,0.35);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 18px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #156466;
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  transition: ease-out 0.4s;
}

.slide_down:hover {
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100px 0 0 #156466;
```

```html
  <div class="button_slide slide_down">Contact HR Now ></div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't illustrate the problem

Comment: Use a background image - The image should only be in the HTML if it's **content** and this isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `background-image` CSS property:

```css
.button_slide {
  color: #156466;
  border: 1px solid rgba(21,100,102,0.35);
  border-radius: 0px;
  /* extend left padding */
  padding: 18px 30px 18px 54px;
  background-image: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1498058230/HR-Connect-Logo_hjbrmn.png);
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #156466;
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  transition: ease-out 0.4s;
}

.slide_down:hover {
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100px 0 0 #156466;
```

```html
<div class="button_slide slide_down">Contact HR Now ></div>
```

To make it appear on top of the `box-shadow` transition effect, you'll need to place it in a pseudo-element:

```css
.button_slide {
  color: #156466;
  border: 1px solid rgba(21,100,102,0.35);
  border-radius: 0px;
  /* extend left padding */
  padding: 18px 30px 18px 54px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #156466;
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  transition: ease-out 0.4s;
}

.slide_down:hover {
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100px 0 0 #156466;
}

.button_slide:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1498058230/HR-Connect-Logo_hjbrmn.png);
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="button_slide slide_down">Contact HR Now ></div>
```

Comment: Anyway to make the image a lot larger without changing the height?

Comment: As big as it can get to fit the height

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Just adjust the `background-size` values

Comment: @Paulie_D How would I make it so once you hover, this white image of the logo comes up instead on the colored one? http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1498062883/HR-Connect-Logowhite_fb7duw.png

Comment: @Paulie_D Would I not just set background-image on :hover? Because that's not working.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki it's poor etiquette to ping someone for help with a new question, when the question that was originally asked has already been resolved. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.